# Change text style of an ionic radio button

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have created a ionic radio button group according to the [ionic doc](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/radio). Here is my code:

```
 <ion-list>
      <ion-radio-group value="biff">
        <ion-list-header class="ion-text-center">
          <ion-label>Organization Type</ion-label>
        </ion-list-header>
    
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Educational</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="ed"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Non educational</ion-label>
          <ion-radio slot="start" value="ned"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
    
      </ion-radio-group>
    </ion-list>
```

I wanted change the style of text of the selected radio button. I am using angular for front end help. How can I achieve this using the corresponding scss file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, here's an example how to apply css to radio button:

```
<ion-radio class="default" ng-class="{'selected': data.clientSide === item.value}" ng-repeat="item in clientSideList" ng-value="item.value" ng-model="data.clientSide" ng-click="choseThis(item)">
        {{ item.text }}    
      </ion-radio>
```

for angular 2+ use [ngClass] https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

See full example: https://codepen.io/shantanu_kulkarrni/pen/QOmvrY